# SMTP Quit responses don't close connections to IIS service

Tags: c#, iis, smtp, iis-6, smtpclient

We're facing an issue in our smtp implementation we can't seem to get resolved.

To draw things out, this is our current setup:

Server A has a .NET Service running, handling queued emails from our application (generated reports that will be send out to clients) 
This is done by using the .NET SMTPClient, with a using block to call the dispose of the smtpclient instance (.NET 4.0), forcing to send the QUIT command.

The message is then sent to Server B where IIS6 is running and handling the SMTP connections, sending out the the message to the client's mailbox.

Now the problem is (seen from the logs): on the dispose for the client on the .NET service on server A will send a QUIT to server B. Server B will then send the QUIT command to the client's mail host, and it's mail hosts seems to respond with a 221, closing the connection.
But then, server B never repsonds to server A, so the connection between the .NET service and the IIS SMTP server is kept open, until they run out of available connections, blocking all new email messages. (There are about 64k open connections by then)

Schematic, it's like this:

.NET SMTP Service (SERVER A) --MSG--> IIS 6 SMTP Server (SERVER B) --MSG--> CLIENT

.NET SMTP Service (SERVER A) --QUIT--> IIS 6 (SERVER B) --QUIT--> CLIENT

.NET SMPT Service (SERVER A) <--X-- IIS 6 (SERVER B) <--221 (conn closed)-- CLIENT

Anyone here can point out our problem/knows how to resolve this? I haven't been able to find a similar issue on the internet...

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Update**

For what's worth: I've tried using the ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout now and setting it to a specific timeout instead of letting it open for an infinite time. Maybe it's not the cleanest solution, but if it closes all open connections between the servers, and not blocking new connections when to many stay open, then our initial issue is solved at least... But we'll need to do some testing first before this can be assured.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://theonetechnologies.com/outsourcing/post/smtpclient-in-net-20-does-not-close-connection-to-mail-server.aspx), there was a bug in the 2.0 framework whereby the SMTPClient didn't has a dispose and didn't send a QUIT, fixed in v4. It may be that there is still a bug in the implementation. (I don't have an SMTP server available to test, I'm afraid. Might be worth posting this as a bug on the MS web site.

(Link found googling "smtpclient not releasing sockets")

Cheers -

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've also read about that QUIT command bug, but when looking in the log, the QUIT is effectively being sent, just the answer seems to get lost between the two servers.
As you suggest, I'll try to post this on the MS buglist, and see whether they can shed some light on this issue...

Comment: If you work for a company and have a volume licence agreement, you might have an MS Account Manager assigned to your company who's job is to help with sort of thing. Alternatively, if you have a MSDN Subscription you will have a number of free support calls with MS. My experience of using these facilities is that they can be really helpful when all else fails.